# Image disappearing when adding a blur

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I load images via LoadQueue:

```
this.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
```

I create my bitmap, this works fine:

```
var myImg = new createjs.Bitmap(this.queue.getResult('test-img'));
    myImg.scaleX = 0.2;
    myImg.scaleY = 0.2;
    myImg.x = 300;
```

I then add a blur:

```
var blurFilter = new createjs.BlurFilter(5, 5, 1);
    myImg.filters = [blurFilter];
    var bounds = blurFilter.getBounds();

    myImg.cache(-50+bounds.x, -50+bounds.y, 100+bounds.width, 100+bounds.height);
```

Then finish up with:

```
this.stage.addChild(myImg);
this.stage.update();
```

The problem is, as soon as I add the blur, the image no longer appears, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented your code and it works well http://jsfiddle.net/k4yhz6oy/2/.

I suppose the cache area of your image is white or transparent.

```
myImg.cache(-50+bounds.x, -50+bounds.y, 100+bounds.width, 100+bounds.height);
```

Apply image bounds to cache

```
var imageBound = myImg.getBounds();
myImg.cache(imageBound.x, imageBound.y, imageBound.width, imageBound.height);
```